# Why is a "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" error being thrown on req.headers even with a null check on my NodeJS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS server running on an elastic beanstalk instance. The logs of the elastic beanstalk instance is showing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Server.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/server.js:48:36)
    at Server.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:784:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
```

The portion of code that is throwing this error is:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if(req.headers.host){
    let httpsHost = req.headers.host.replace('8081', '8443');
    res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + httpsHost + req.url});
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(8081);
```

The purpose of this code is to force redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

The server is **working normally**, but this error is getting thrown on a constant basis. I see no adverse effects on the server from this error, but it is making my logs look terrible.

1. Why is this error even happening? Why do some `req.headers` not have a `host` variable defined?
2. Why is my null check not preventing this error?

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, but it may help for you to put `console.log(req.headers.host);` somewhere to see the actual value of it.

Comment: `if(req.headers.host)` only checks if its truthy so if it would be `{}` or `[]` it would still step into the if block